# How to remove this future warning when making timzone changes to data in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timezone

I have the following code:

```
time = calendar.iat[i, j]
time = dt.datetime.strptime(str(time), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z')  # converts the time to a datetime object 
time = time.replace(tzinfo=from_zone)  # notes the current timezone of the object 
time = time.astimezone(to_zone)  # converts the object to the desired timezone 
calendar.iat[i, j] = time  # commits the change to the dataframe
```

where

```
from_zone = tz.gettz('UTC')
to_zone = tz.gettz('America/New_York')
```

Calendar in this case is a Pandas Dataframe that contains UTC + 0 datetimes. I need to convert these datetimes to UTC -4/-5 (see an example below as to what is happening).

[image: before the first data point was converted]

[image: after the first data point was converted]

The way I am doing this is by looping over the data-frame and replacing these one by one (not the most efficient method, but I still need to learn how to implement vectorization properly). This being said, if I execute this line of code:

```
calendar.iat[i, j] = time  # commits the change to the dataframe
```

then I get the following warning:

```
FutureWarning: Setitem-like behavior with mismatched timezones is deprecated and
will change in a future version. Instead of raising (or for Index, Series, and
DataFrame methods, coercing to object dtype),the value being set (or passed as a
fill_value, or inserted) will be cast to the existing DatetimeArray/DatetimeIndex
/Series/DataFrame column's timezone. To retain the old behavior, explicitly cast
to object dtype before the operation.
calendar.iat[i, j] = time  # commits the change to the dataframe
```

Having googled this specific alert, I did not come up with anything worthwhile. Can someone explain to me what this alert means and how would I remove it? Is Pandas suggesting here another way of changing the time zones of the dates? The code works fine in general and the dates are converted properly to their required timezone.

The imports I am using for this code are:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
from datetime import time
from dateutil import tz
```

Comment: What is `from_zone` and `to_zone` ?

Comment: Good question: "from zone = tz.gettz('UTC')" and "to_zone = tz.gettz('America/New_York')" where tz is "from dateutil import tz". I will update my message so this is clear.

Comment: in principle, if working with time zones in pandas, try using the built-in functionality [pd.to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html), [pd.Series.dt.tz_localize](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.tz_localize.html) and [pd.Series.dt.tz_convert](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.tz_convert.html).

Comment: So you would say its simply the matter of the fact that my imports dont mix well and if I would switch to a full Pandas solution it should be fine?

Comment: Well you *can* work with native Python datetime and dateutil in combination with pandas, I'd just not recommend it (unless absolutely needed) since pure pandas in this case & my experience is less error-prone, more readable (opinionanted...) and more efficient (no loops in the Python script for example).

Comment: maybe you could add exemplary content of `calendar` to the question.

Comment: That makes sense, I will do so ASAP.

Comment: @Noir - I hope duplicate help, if not let me know.

Comment: My question is why does this warning pop up @jezrael its not how to convert timzones in Pandas. I do know that there might be better methods of doing so and that mine might not be the best, but this is a unique question, as far as I can tell and I did not find an answer to it. My code is converting the timezones perfectly fine otherwise.

Comment: Hmm, so if use answer from dupe is not removed warning?

Comment: I do not know, I will definitely try that method out, but beyond removing the error, I also want to have an explanation for the error in question. I have now also updated my post with the screenshots of the data within the calendar dataframe.

Comment: similar to the answers to the q that @jezrael linked, you just need to e.g. `pd.to_datetime(calendar["market_open"]).dt.tz_convert("America/New_York")`

Comment: I will test it out and come back to you.

Comment: Hi @FObersteiner this is an excellent solution, much shorter than what I had. Can you perhaps also tell me if there is a way to redefine calendar["market_open"] so I don't need to declare calendar["market_open"] and calendar["market_close"] in two separate lines? Since if I leave the column name empty I get a key error.

Comment: not sure what you mean by "redefine" but I'd make it two separate lines anyway for readability; `calendar["market_open"] = pd.to_datetime(calendar["market_open"]).dt. ...` and the same for "market_close". You could also create new columns to keep the original info; e.g. "market_close_lt" with "lt" meaning local time for example.

Comment: Ok fair enough, in that case I simply made two lines as you suggested:

calendar["market_open"] = pd.to_datetime(calendar["market_open"]).dt.tz_convert(to_zone)

calendar["market_close"] = pd.to_datetime(calendar["market_close"]).dt.tz_convert(to_zone)


Thanks a lot once again!